# Setting a cookie in Wordpress functions.php - cant echo it using an other function

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

My first function gets the parameters from the URL and sets the cookies:

**Edit:**

first function loads before everything on WP 
and saves the cookies 
and when checking the browsers cookies - it's there. it's saved.

```
/**
    Get variables from the URL and set them into the coockie
**/

add_action( 'init', 'set_utm_cookie');
function set_utm_cookie() {

    global $utm;

    if (getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR');
    else if(getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED'))
       $utm['ip'] = getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED');
    else if(getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'))
        $utm['ip'] = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
    else
        $utm['ip'] = 'UNKNOWN';

    $utm = array(
        'utm_source'   => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_source"]),
        'utm_medium'   => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_medium"]),
        'utm_term'     => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_term"]),
        'utm_content'  => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_content"]),
        'utm_campaign' => htmlspecialchars( $_GET["utm_content"]), 
        'ip'           => $utm['ip']
    );


if ( !isset($_COOKIE['utm_source']) ) {
    setcookie('utm_source',   $utm['utm_source'],   time()+3600*60*24*7); 
}


if ( !isset($_COOKIE['utm_medium']) ) {
    setcookie('utm_medium',   $utm['utm_medium'],   time()+3600*60*24*7);
}

if ( !isset($_COOKIE['utm_term']) ) {   
    setcookie('utm_term',     $utm['utm_term'],     time()+3600*60*24*7);
}

if ( !isset($_COOKIE['utm_content']) ) {
    setcookie('utm_content',  $utm['utm_content'],  time()+3600*60*24*7);
}

if ( !isset($_COOKIE['utm_campaign']) ) {
    setcookie('utm_campaign', $utm['utm_campaign'], time()+3600*60*24*7);
}

if ( !isset($_COOKIE['ip']) ) {
    setcookie('ip',           $utm['ip'],           time()+3600*60*24*7);
}



}
```

the second function is activated using ajax 
Whenever a user submits a contact form - It sends the inputs to  this function and sends the email. 
if the email is sent (using wp_mail function - it sends the same email but with what I saved in the cookie. )

when I get the email - the fields of the coolie output is blank :X except of the IP. I get the IP.

```
/**
    Contact form using Ajax 
**/ 

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 

// Send information from the contact form 
function submit_contact_form(){

    // Get the UTM variables from the 'get_the_utm_vars()' function
    //$utm = get_the_utm_vars();

    // If there is a $_POST['email']...
    if( isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['validation'] == true ) ) {

        // Get parameters
        $email = $_POST['email']; // Gets the email of the user..
        $email_to = "arik@example.pro";
        $walid = 'walid@example.pro';
        $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
        $message = $_POST['text']; 
        $email_subject = "yellowHEAD Intro: $email";        
        $headers = array(
                'From: '. $fullname .' <'. $email .'>', 
                'BCC:  yonatan@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  gal@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  eran@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  tova@example.pro', 
                'BCC:  walid@example.pro', 
                'Content-type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"; format=flowed \r\n'
            ); 

        // Send email to YH, and if sent - do:
        if ( wp_mail($email_to,$email_subject,$message,$headers) ) {

            // Tells me that the mail has been sent
            echo json_encode( array("result"=>"complete") );


            //Add the UTM variables to the emails text
            $message .= "\r\n \r\n \r\n UTM Campaign: ".$_COOKIE['utm_campaign']." \r\n UTM Medium: ".$_COOKIE['utm_medium']." \r\n UTM Term: ".$_COOKIE['utm_term'] ."\r\n UTM Content: ".$_COOKIE['utm_content']." \r\n UTM Campaign: ".$_COOKIE['utm_campaign']." ";


            // A mail for tova with the UTM paramseters
            wp_mail($walid,$email_subject,$message);

            // An automail for the user 
            //$message_responce = "Hi $fullname, \r\n Thanks for reaching out to us with your inquiry. We have received your e-mail and somebody from yellowHEAD will respond to you within one working day. \r\n In the meantime, feel free to connect with us through our Facebook or LinkedIn or to check out our professional blog. \r\n \r\n Talk to you soon. \r\n - The yellowHEAD Team";
            //$header_responce = 'From: yellowHEADinc.com Team <info@exampleinc.com>';
            //wp_mail($email,'yellowHEAD - Thanks For Your E-mail',$message_responce,$header_responce );

        } else {
            echo json_encode(array("result"=>"mail_error"));
            var_dump($GLOBALS['phpmailer']->ErrorInfo);
    }
        wp_die();
    }

}
```

How do I echo these cookies right? 
I'm almost sure there is something basic I don't know that will solve everything :X

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey6TH.png
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the cookies are being set? (I personally like Firebugs Cookies tab to check this http://getfirebug.com/cookies)

Comment: Does the AJAX run on the same domain / protocol?

Comment: @tvgemert yes. I checked using firebug this second. and yes. they are on the same domain.

Comment: What does `print_r($_COOKIE)` get you?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I used `print_r($_COOKIE)` on the first function one - I got all the cookies. 

I used `print_r($_COOKIE)` on the second function and I got '0'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding cookie path and cookie domain

```
setcookie('utm_campaign',$utm['utm_campaign'] , time()+3600*24*100, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
```

Comment: I used the wrong cookie path the whole time :'( 
TNX !